# how can we hide/disable workflow history of approval workflow in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

[image: The image in which i wants the third option which i circled to be disabled or hide]Hi,

Iam using the default sharepoint approval workflow,as per my client requirement is like they dont want the workflow history to be displayed to user..i am sending the image of the workflow history page...can anyone please guide me from this issue..

Thanks in Advance,
Naresh.

Answer (score 1):

I did some snooping around and unfortunately I didn't find an easy way to do this as there is no explicit CSS defined for just the workflow history section that you update to hide it. Here are some not quite as friendly options:

- Use Javascript / jquery to find the Workflow History element and manually change the styling inline via javascript
- Update the WrkStat.aspx page so that it doesn't show the Workflow History folder - I really don't recommend this because if SharePoint becomes patched there is a good chance the file will get overwritten and you will lose the changes you made.
- Copy the WrkStat.aspx page to make your own and create a workflow / column that links to your custom page instead. It may also be possible to update the link on the view using javascript which may be less work. This could also be challenging if they find the workflow status page through other means (emails, other pages, etc.)
- Don't log to the workflow history list and just let it be blank. Log to another list entirely, or utilize the ULS / Event Logs.